# How to change lambda function trigger of API gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli

Hi So I had two different Lambda functions(Lambda1, Lambda2) and two different API Gateway(API1 API2)If currently the connection is API1 --> Lambda1 and AP2 --> Lambda2. From AWS CLI I was trying to make it API1 --> Lambda2 and API2 --> Lambda1 from running below commands.

```
       aws apigateway put-integration --rest-api-id ###### \
                                                --resource-id ######\
                                                --http-method POST \
                                                --type AWS \
                                                --integration-http-method POST \
                                                --uri arn:aws-cn:apigateway:region:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/<function:arn>/invocations \
                                                --region region
```

But it was not working and giving me the below error
`does not include a resource with path /* having an integration <LambdaARN>`

I also tried with type: AWS_PROXY